# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations OperationId ignored

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I've upgraded my code to use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` 3.0.0. (
`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations`, `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger`, `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen`, `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI` all are 3.0.0).

And now when I use `[SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "MyUniqueId")]`
the `operationId` value is not set, but auto generated.

Any idea how if I am doing something wrong or is it just a new version bug?

Comment: Hotfix is downgrade back to version 2.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the same issue.
After looking at the documentation, found the solution.
You need to add the line `c.EnableAnnotations()` in your startup file, more precisely,

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.EnableAnnotations();
```

More details are [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#install-and-enable-annotations).
Hope this helps you to!